# CSS: updating justify-content value based on presence of child element

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have the following small snippet:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  
  .btn {
    font-size: 12px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h3>This heading wont always be here</h3>
  <button class="btn">This button always will and should be on the right</button>
</div>
```

Basically its a header that will always contain the button (which should always be positioned on the right) and a heading (which is optional).

At times, a heading will not exist and therefore the button will sit on the left hand side, I know that updating the `justify-content` property to `flex-end` achieves the outcome I want (in the chrome inspector) but how can I update my CSS to make this check? Ie, if no `<h3>`, then use `justify-content: flex-end` instead of `space-between`?

I tried using the `not` selector like this but to no avail:

```
:not(h3) {
   justify-content: flex-end;
}
```

Comment: _"how can I update my CSS to make this check?"_ - you can't, not really. You would need something like the `:has` pseudo class - but that has poor browser support yet. But you can add `margin-left: auto` to your button.

Comment: This seems to be the cleanest solution, thank you! If you'd like to add this as an answer I'd be happy to assign it as the answer :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> how can I update my CSS to make this check?

You can't, not really. You would need something like the `:has` pseudo class - but that has poor browser support yet. (See also, [Is there a CSS parent selector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector))

But you can add `margin-left: auto` to your button.

Answer (score 1):

Add `margin-left: auto` to `.btn` class, check below code
I hope it works

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.btn {
    font-size: 12px;
    margin-left: auto;
  }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h3>This heading wont always be here</h3>
  <button class="btn">This button always will and should be on the right</button>
</div>
 <br>
 <br>

<div class="container">
  <button class="btn">This button always will and should be on the right</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can absolutely position so that you don't need to worry about the div being present or not!

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  width:100%;
  
}
  .btn {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    right:0px;
  }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h3>This heading wont always be here</h3>
  <button class="btn">This button always will and should be on the right</button>
</div>
```

Comment: How does this cope with narrow viewports or longer heading?

Comment: @AHaworth I am trying to fulfill user requirements, not a complete solution!

Answer (score 0):

You could use grid rather than flex and force the button into the second column.

This snippet assumes you always want the text of the button to fit on one line but of course you could alter things using max-.... and so on depending on what you want on very narrow viewports or when you have a very long h3 text.

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  justify-content: space-between;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr auto;
}

.btn {
  font-size: 12px;
  text-align: right;
  display: inline-block;
  width: fit-content;
  grid-column: 2 / span 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h3>This heading wont always be here</h3>
  <button class="btn">This button always will and should be on the right</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can swap the order of the elements (`h3`and `button`) in the HTML code and use `flex-direction: row-reverse`. That way the first element (i.e. the `button`) will always be on the right, regardless if there is a second element:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.btn {
  font-size: 12px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <button class="btn">This button always will and should be on the right</button>
  <h3>This heading wont always be here</h3>
</div>
<br>
<br>
<div class="container">
  <button class="btn">This button is on the right</button>
</div>
```